# SignalR for 2 web pages

Tags: signalr

I am using .net project and create one web page to use with SignalR. This code below working with one web page. Client side:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { });

var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {  };
```

Server side:

```
var context = 
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SignalRChat.ChatHub>();          
context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

Then I create second web page and copy client and server code from page 1.
Problem is that when I call

```
context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
```

from second page. it fired function

```
chat.client.broadcastMessage
```

on first page. How can I fixed that to fired client side for page 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it to fire on both pages -

I suspect you did not create a connection on the page 2. Once you have a valid connection on page 2 it would fire on both page 1 and 2 if you had both open. Or only on the page you have open.

If you want it to fire on each page but not both pages you have some changes to make. You have several options you can go with here with no additional context:

1. Really simple - rename chat.client.broadcastMessage on page 2 to something else and call it from the server with a new method.
2. Look into Groups - updating context.Clients.Group(groupname).broadcastMessage(name, message) you can send messages to users on page1 (assuming you have a group for page 1 and page 2) and then only send messages to users on page 2 when needed.